# representing CFG productions

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

I'm working on a program that needs to decide if a string "(example + another) * other" belongs to a certain grammar.

```
    Start = Expr endline
    Expr  = Term Expr2
    Expr2 = + Term Expr2 | - Term Expr2 | e
    Term  = Factor Term2
    Term2 = * Factor Term2 | / Factor Term2 | e
    Factor= id | ( Expr ) | num
```

For example I'm trying to implement something similar to above grammar in Java. So far I have switch statements with recusion but I feel this is not the way to do it.
Are there simpler ways of representing productions?
Any tips would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I suggest you read up on parsers. Here's a few keywords for you: LR-parsing, LL-parsing, first-sets, recursive descent :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch statements with recursion is a lot closer to what you need than you might think.

See my answer on [how to build a recursive descent parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769).